# Can't correctly save a Pandas dataframe that contains a column with sets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a column with sets. When I save the dataframe using `.to_csv()` and then re-open it with `pd.read_csv()`, the column that contained sets now contains strings.

Here is a code example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[1,2,3], 'sets':[set('abc'),set('XYZ'),set([1,2,3])]})
print(type(df.sets[0])) # Type = set

df.to_csv('xxx/test.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('xxx/test.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
print(type(df.sets[0])) # Type = str
```

Is there a way to avoid the type changing ? I can't find which parameter from either `.to_csv()` or `pd.read_csv()` controls this behavior.

The only way I found to get around this problem is by using pickle but I'm guessing there is a way of doing it with Pandas.

Comment: In the end the simplest solution is to use Pandas' `.to_pickle()` and `.read_pickle()` when dealing with dataframes that contain objects such as sets or other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what a csv file is? It is just a text file. You can open it with vi or notepad to make sure.

That means that what is saved in a csv file is just a text representation of the fields. `read_csv` does its best to convert back integer and floating point values. It can even find date if you use the `parse_date` parameter.

Here you could use `ast.literal_eval` as a custom converter:

```
import ast
...
df = pd.read_csv('xxx/test.csv', header=0, index_col=0,
                 converters={'sets': ast.literal_eval})
```